# php 5.2.17 to php 5.4.4 encoding issues

Tags: php

I'm having issues updating to php 5.4.4 since my database records are show in browser with errors.
I've searched and many people said they had to make fixes on they code, but no one says wich fixes they made.

So since I'm not a php expert, I'm asking here help to point me in the right way.

what I want "á é í ó ú"

I've

```
<form id="editar" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">
```

on submit my php does this

```
$txt_edi = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text_to_edit'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
$query = $ligacao -> prepare("UPDATE mytable SET description = '".utf8_encode($txt_edi)."' ");
```

ok, on php 5.2.17 my mysql record is like " Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº "

on php 3.4.4 my mysql record is like this " á é í ó ú "

So I'm assuming something has changed in utf8_encode otherwise my record would be the same in both php vertions...

NOTE that if I dont add the third parameter to htmlspecialchars in php 5.4.4 my string gets empty ( if I change to UTF-8 it gets empty too ), in 5.2.17 it goes to database with no problem.

Comment: what if you do not use utf8_decode? what encoding does your website use?

Comment: Why do you decode the utf8 don't you need utf8 for é.

Comment: with no utf8_decode I get this: Fichas tÃƒÂ©cnicas, I need to utf8_encode / decode because my mother language uses á é í ó ú ç ã and so on. So to avoid problems my database records are encoded

Comment: couldn't you simply use utf8 for the response charset and keep it all utf8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My educated guess (given your alarming lack of code) is that you are using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). That function has changed the default value for its third-argument in PHP/5.4—from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8`:

> **encoding**
>
> From PHP 5.6.0, `default_charset` value is used as default. **From PHP 5.4.0, UTF-8 is the default. PHP prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is used as the default.** Although this argument is technically optional, you are
>   highly encouraged to specify the correct value for your code.

Solution: always provide the third parameter.

---

**Edit: some random thoughts about updated question**

App (supposedly) uses ISO-8859-1 but you force the browser to convert to UTF-8:

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

When you receive the form you process it as if it was ISO-8859-1 (which it isn't):

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['text_to_edit'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1')
```

Finally you convert from fake ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8:

```
utf8_encode($txt_edi)
```

... and you inject the untrusted input into a SQL statement:

```
"UPDATE mytable SET description = '".utf8_encode($txt_edi)."' "
```

... even though your database class apparently supports prepared statements:

```
 $query = $ligacao -> prepare(...)
```

Nothing in this code illustrates the problem in the original question (*displaying* data) but I have the impression that either it works in PHP/5.2 by pure chance or stuff in database is already corrupted (or both).

At this point, I'd normally suggest switching everything to UTF-8 and forgetting about encodings and conversions forever. But there's an added problem: you convert to HTML *before* storing in the database.

So, sorry, I'm completely lost. I'll gladly remove this answer if you consider it isn't' useful.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code, I really didn't know what to post. Yes, I've htmlspecialchars, not in the example I gave but on the rest of the project. I did add htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');, it allow me to edit entryes to correct them, but they are so many... I need to find a compatible way of make this work in both 5.2.xxx and newer php releases, since my webserver is 5.2.xx and my localhost is 5.4.4

Comment: I don't understand your comment but your description suggests that that this wasn't the issue. In fact, using wrong encoding in `htmlspecialchars()` normally makes the whole string disappear. I suspect you're relying on default encodings everywhere and you've also upgraded Apache and MySQL.

Comment: I believe Apache and MySql are the same, since I'm using MAMP wich allow me to switch from 5.2.17 to 5.4.4 on localhost. I'm edditing my post to see if it clears things, can you please have a look in a few minutes? thanks

Comment: No, your answer IS usefull since I'm learning that I made much big mistakes here. Now you said " App (supposedly) uses ISO-8859-1 ". How can I confirm that? all my php files have header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');, my form also has the accept-charset="UTF-8", database is utf8, what I'm missing? Thanks an sorry for the mess

Comment: Why did you mention ISO-8859-1 in the first place? It's like asking how to verify if you are using PHP—it's an intentional decision.

Comment: I didn't... This is the answer, "At this point, I'd normally suggest switching everything to UTF-8 and forgetting about encodings and conversions forever"